# Getting points along a line given heading, starting point and distance between points

Tags: c, geometry

I am currently working on my research and coding my theories to simulate scenarios.

I need a way to incrementally find points along a given heading (angle between a line and the positive x axis) given the heading, the starting point, and the distance between the points. The new points should be in the direction of the heading. I am somehow facing a difficulty on how I should go about doing this.

With enough time I can come up with a way myself, but given that sharpening my coding skills is not my final outcome here and I would rather spend more time experimenting with my theory, I was wondering if anyone could help me find a solution. I am working with C, so a solution in C would be preferred and not one that uses library functions available in other languages.

Comment: What's the question? This sounds like a trig problem, not a coding problem.

Comment: I have a point (x,y). I have a heading angle A. I would like to generate coordinates of more points along that heading A from point (x,y). I am stuck on how to implement this with an efficient code in C.

Comment: `x^2 + y^2 = r^2`, the angle is `θ = tan^-1(y/x)`. Then successive points is `(x*r cos θ,  x*r sin θ)`  for integer x.

Comment: The main issue here is how you package up the information in the call to the function that does this job — or how you wrap a loop around the code.  It seems like you should be able to use the distance `d` between points, plus the angle `A` (in radians!) and the start point (`x0`, `y0`) to generate a new point (`x1`, `y1`) using basic mathematics: `x1 = x0 + d * cos(A); y1 = y0 + d * sin(A);`.  It ain't rocket science.

Comment: Thank you @BurnsBA.   Jonathan, I have not done basic Trig in quite a while. That is why I was finding it difficult to visualize the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a unit vector in the direction you want

for example lets say you want 45 degrees, the unit vector would be 
<1/sqrt(2), 1/sqrt(2)>. this distance would be 1 since its a unit vector so you can scale it by the distance you want per point. so lets say you want each point to be 1/3 of a unit, then you would just multiply the unit vector and get 
<1/(3sqrt(2)), 1/(3sqrt(2))> and then you can just do a loop. so if you want 10 points in that direction it would just be

```
unitvector = calculateUnitVector()
unitvector *= distanceBetweenPoints
for(i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
   drawPoint(startPoint + unitVector * i)
}
```

i hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. This certainly helps to visualize the problem better from a coding perspective.

Comment: I can write out more of the code for you if you would like, but this strategy should get you what you want.

Comment: Thank you, but that will be nice of you and lazy of me. I will try myself and ask again if I fail.